# What is csrss.exe?

Tags: process, task-manager

According to google, CSRSS.exe could either be a Trojan, or an important part of Windows.

eh!

They say:

> This process should be treated as
>   suspicious if there are two instances
>   running. Always take note of the
>   process location when trying to
>   determine whether or not the process
>   is genuine or malicious.This Windows
>   component should be located in your
>   Windows System directory ie: something
>   similar to
>   C:\Windows\System32\csrss.exe

I have 2 instances that seem to be running, but both point to the same file in C:\Windows\System32

Should I be worried?

My anti-virus doesn't complain... (panda cloud)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my laptop (Windows 7 Enterprise) I have 2 csrss.exe processes running. So I don't think you should worry about it.

If you want to to investigate it more I would recommend using the tool "Process Explorer":
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: I have two as well. It's normal.

Comment: +1 for ProcExp. It even lets you verify the digital signatures of processes (all Windows core executables are signed by Microsoft).

Answer (score 3):

I would download Malwarebye and Microsoft security essentials and check with them. Run full scans.

Edit: Your question asks what it is. Here is some info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client/Server_Runtime_Subsystem

Answer (score 2):

You have to differentiate [csrSs.exe](http://www.neuber.com/taskmanager/process/csrss.exe.html) (system process) and [csrCs.exe](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=csrcs.exe&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) (a virus)